# AngularJs variables not getting set from Jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Newbie to angular and jasmine. I have a situation in my tests where my variables aren't getting asserted to the right values in my `expect` statements, even though they work as expected in my controller. Here is my actual controller code for which I am writing jasmine unit tests, basically performing save actions on a user click:

```js
function performSaveTrackActions() {

  var releaseSlug = vm.selected.album.slug;
  var trackSlug = vm.selected.track.fileName;
  var trackData = vm.formTrack;

  // calls the backend service to save the data
  var trackSaveResponse = trackService.saveTrack(releaseSlug, trackSlug, trackData, vm.currentWorkspace).then(function(saveTrackResponse) {

    if (saveTrackResponse.status == 202) {

      statusMessageService.successMsg("Successfully saved the track " + vm.selected.track.title);
      vm.selected.track = vm.formTrack; // Assigning the original var to modified after successful save
      return releaseService.currentRelease(releaseSlug, vm.currentWorkspace);

    } else {
      statusMessageService.errorMsg("Error: Could not save the track " + vm.selected.track.title);
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    vm.selected.album.data.tracks = response.data.tracks;
    vm.selectTrack(vm.selected.album, vm.selected.track);
    setTrackLevelDates();
  });
  return trackSaveResponse;
}
```

Here is my test, where the line `vm.selected.track = vm.formTrack` should assign it correctly, but doesn't for some reason and expectation fails:

```js
describe('Test for Happy path when saving a track', function() {
      beforeEach(inject(function($q) {
        mockStatusMessageService.successMsg.and.returnValue("Successfully saved the track " + vm.selected.track.title);
        mockTrackService.saveTrack.and.returnValue($q.when(mockTrackSaveResponse));
        vm.formTrack = mockFormTrack;
        vm.selected.track = anotherMockedOriginalData
      }));
      it('interactions when a track is successfully saved', function(done) {

        vm.performSaveTrackActions().then(function() {

          // after successful save, I expect that the two values should be same but they error out saying both are different.
          expect(vm.selected.track.albumArtist).toEqual(mockFormTrack.albumArtist);
        });

        scope.$apply();
        done();
      });
    ...
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What does your mock of the service look like?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship `mockTrackSaveResponse = {data: "", status: 202, config: Object, statusText: "Accepted"};`
and

Comment: `mockFormTrack = {
    "fileName": "i-am-a-fileName.mp3",
    "title": "Modified title",
    "artists": "Modified artist",
    "genre": "Modified genre",
    "releaseTitle": "La Polícia",
    "codec": "mp3",
    "channels": "Stereo",
    "bitRate": "256",
    "bitsPerSample": "16",
    "samplingRate": "44100",
    "sequenceNumber": 1,
    "trackLength": 243,
    "diskNumber": 1,
    "albumArtist": "Modified track Artist",
    "composer": "ContentOps",
    "year": 2016,
    "md5Hash": "32a8ce043e7fad643f124e1990bb6391"
   };`

Comment: There is nothing in that mock that's going to resolve the promise so your expect line won't run.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Can you elaborate ? Sorry newbie here. Also, what do you recommend then as a solution

Comment: I think that your mock of the service should return a promise and resolve it (see $q.when). I typically provide mocks by just loading a js file that re-declares the dependency after or instead of the "real" service in the karma.config file.

Comment: That's what I am doing in my beforeEach, right ?

Comment: `mockTrackService.saveTrack.and.returnValue($q.when(mockTrackSaveResponse));`

Comment: Good point. I tend not to do that setup in each spec, preferring to just override the entire service, so I wasn't looking there.

Comment: What's your code in vm.selectTrack? Does the test for it work as expected?

Comment: Yes @AmyBlankenship. It works as expected in the code. It basically assigns the current selection with the formData (vm.formTrack). And It does that if I step through it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115556/discussion-between-noobcoder-and-amy-blankenship).